# Extracting parameters from astropy.modeling Gaussian2D

Tags: python, modeling, astropy

I have managed to use `astropy.modeling` to model a 2D Gaussian over my image and the parameters it has produced to fit the image seem reasonable. However, I need to run the 2D Gaussian over thousands of images because we are interested in examining the mean x and y of the model and also the x and y standard deviations over our images. The model output looks like this:

```
m2
<Gaussian2D(amplitude=0.0009846091239480168, x_mean=30.826676737477573, y_mean=31.004045976953222, x_stddev=2.5046722491074536, y_stddev=3.163048479350727, theta=-0.0070295894129793896)>
```

I can also tell you this:

```
type(m2)
<class 'astropy.modeling.functional_models.Gaussian2D'>
Name: Gaussian2D
Inputs: (u'x', u'y')
Outputs: (u'z',)
Fittable parameters: ('amplitude', 'x_mean', 'y_mean', 'x_stddev', 'y_stddev', 'theta')
```

What I need is a method to extract the parameters of the model, namely:

```
x_mean
y_mean
x_stddev
y_stddev
```

I am not familiar with this form output so I am really stuck on how to extract the parameters.

Comment: For thousands of images make sure you are using a model set: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/index.html#model-sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models have attributes you can access:

```
from astropy.modeling import models
g2d = models.Gaussian2D(1,2,3,4,5)
g2d.amplitude.value  # 1.0
g2d.x_mean.value     # 2.0
g2d.y_mean.value     # 3.0
g2d.x_stddev.value   # 4.0
g2d.y_stddev.value   # 5.0
```

You need to extract these values after you fitted the model but you can access them in the same way: `.<name>.value`.

You can also extract them in one go but then you need to keep track which parameter is in which position:

```
g2d.parameters    # array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  0.])
# Amplitude
g2d.parameters[0] # 1.0
# x-mean
g2d.parameters[1] # 2.0
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use estimate_line_parameters. The docs for it aren't very clear in this area (or so I think). If the problem is getting starting parameters for the Gaussians for the lines, it is a good place to start.

To approach it this way:

```
from specutils.spectra import Spectrum2D
from specutils.fitting import estimate_line_parameters
```

...

```
e1 = estimate_line_parameters(spectrum, models.Gaussian2D())
a = e1.amplitude.value
b = e1.x_mean.value
c = e1.y_mean.value
d = x_stddev.value
e = y_stddev.value
```

estimate_line_parameters gives the results loads of decimal places, so if you are trying to *estimate* starting values you would probably want to use round(value_name, n) where n is the number of dec places that you feel are appropriate.

**NOTE** that a,b,c etc are returned as values and don't preserve units. so you will also need:

```
from astropy import units as u
```

and then (e.g.) a = e1.amplitude.value*u.(flux_units) where flux_units is Jy or something similar and/or scaled versions thereof.

Of course all this assumes that you have got your background sufficiently well subtracted...